# Membership type defaults upon renewal

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

We are planning to restructure our membership types slightly later this year. We will eliminate two or three categories and change the amounts (up) and possibly the names.

Right now, the renewal default on the membership type radio button appears to be the current membership type. We would like to manage what the default is when the existing membership type is obsolete. I can only find how to manage the default on new memberships, not renewals. The documentation doesn’t seem to help.

We are Joomla.